Google Auth with Cordova/Ionic
I'm currently working on an Ionic/Angular project that utilizes Cordova for mobile app development. I've hit a roadblock with user authentication, specifically integrating Google Authentication. The cordova-plugin-googleplus library, which I initially considered for this purpose, appears to be outdated and archived. I'm seeking advice or alternative solutions to implement Google Auth in my project.
Has anyone successfully integrated Google Authentication in a similar tech stack recently? I'm open to suggestions, including migrating to other plugins or technologies that work well with Ionic/Angular/Cordova.
Here's what my environment looks like:

Ionic (7.3)
Cordova (9.0.0)

I've read about potentially using Firebase Authentication directly or switching to Capacitor in place of Cordova for a more up-to-date solution. However, I'm not entirely sure how to proceed with these options or if there are other preferable alternatives.
What's the best and easiest solution?

The best solution would be to migrate your project from Cordova to Capacitor. Ionic provides how to do this here. Then use a capacitor version of the google auth. There are several working ones and both have several blogs on how to set this up and get it working. All you have to do is a quick google search:

@capacitor-firebase/authentication
@codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth

Goodluck!
